# synchronizing the git local master with the remote master branch created uncommitted commits

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull

I am new to git and I tried to update my local master branch with the remote master(I am using visual studio). I fetched the changes and pulled them into my local branch but then I have the incoming changes as uncommitted changes so I can't checkout to any other branch. I know that we shouldn't push into the master branch and the uncommitted changes are coming from my colleague. I undo the changes in my local master branch but it is still like the following image:

[image]

How can I fix this problem and update my master branch without overwriting anything in remote master?

Comment: “I have the incoming changes as uncommitted changes” No, you don’t. Only commits travel. Nothing uncommitted even exists as far as git is concerned. “the uncommitted changes are coming from my colleague” No, they are not. Only you can see uncommitted things on your machine. They do not come from anywhere.

Comment: Yes but now you need to clarify. What’s the real problem? What does `git status` say?

Comment: the `git status` returns "your ranch is behind 'origin/master' by 400 commits" and I have number of untracked files. I can not pull because there are uncommitted changes. I have undone the uncommitted changes because I was assumed that these uncommitted changes should not be committed to the master branch.

Comment: You are not showing the whole of what `git status` says, so that's not very helpful. However, what stops you from pushing?